# Can a function be called inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JS/React/JSX novice here, running experiments in codepen to see how well I can work with this stuff...

I can't seem to get my react component to recognize and use a simple function when returning renderable JSX.   Here's the code...

```
const Myfunc = (a,b) => {return (a+b)}

const MyComp = (props) => {
  return <h1>
    Hello, <br/>
    {props.name}, <br/> 
    How are you {props.when} <br/>  
    See this list... {props.list} ? <br/>
    propsa = {props.a} <br/>
    propsb = {props.b} <br/>
    directSum = {(props.a + props.b)} <br/>
    sumFromCall = {Myfunc(props.a + props.b)}
  </h1>;
}

const element = <MyComp 
   name="Moe Howard"  
   when="Now" 
   list={['a','b','c']} 
   a={1} 
   b={2}
   />;

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It returns...

```
Hello,
Moe Howard,
How are you Now
See this list... abc ?
propsa = 1
propsb = 2
directSum = 3
sumFromCall = NaN
```

For the `sumFromCall` line (last line), I would have expected 3 instead of `NaN` (what does "NaN" mean anyway ?)

But this works fine...

```
const Myfunc = (a,b) => {return (a+b)}
const element = <h1> {Myfunc(3,5)} </h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

returns "8" as expected

I thought this might have been a scoping problem so I moved `MyFunc` inside the `MyComp` component and tried that.  No dice.

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` means "Not a Number" (this is searchable).

You're passing `props.a + props.b` into `Myfunc`, a function that expects two parameters. In the version that works, you pass two parameters in.

This means `b` is `undefined` inside `Myfunc`. `3 + undefined` is `NaN`.

You likely meant:

```js
sumFromCall = {Myfunc(props.a, props.b)}
```

Comment: DUH... (facepalm).  pros.a,props.b, of course.
You know when you can't see the forest for the trees ?
My bad.  

Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @daveg We all live in forests of trees; only the forrsts change. FWIW one way to debug stuff like this is to just put the function into a REPL and call it the same way, or log the params in the function.